# For loop double the result just for a certain item in an array

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, double, formatter

So I use a for loop but somehow it loops 2 times for the first and the last item in the array. I tried and it apparently just happens when the len_a bigger than the rest (len_b and len_c)

So here's my code:

```
def arithmetic_arranger(problems):
    top = ""
    middle = ""
    lines = ""
    bottom = ""
    for problem in problems:
        #split em up
        nums = problem.split(" ")
        first_num = nums[0]
        symbol = nums[1]
        last_num = nums[2]
        if len(first_num) > 4 < len(last_num):
            return "gk boleh lebih dr 4 yhhhh"
        
        #find the total
        if symbol == "+":
            total = str(int(first_num) + int(last_num))
        elif symbol == "-":
            total = str(int(first_num) - int(last_num))
        else:
            return "cuma boleh + or - tolol"
        
        #find the distances for the top line
        len_a = len(first_num)
        len_b = len(last_num)
        len_c = len(total)
        maxi = max(len_a, len_b, len_c)
        lines = lines + "--" +"-" * maxi + "     "
        if maxi == len_a:
            top = top + " "*2 + first_num + "     "
            middle = middle + symbol + " " + " " * (len_a - len_b) + last_num + "     "
            bottom = bottom + "  " + " " * (len_a - len_c) + total + "     "
        if maxi == len_b:
            top = top + " "*2 + " " * (len_b - len_a) + first_num + "     "
            middle = middle + symbol + " " + last_num + "     "
            bottom = bottom + "  " + " " * (len_b - len_c) + total + "     "
        else:
            top = top + " "*2 + " " * (len_c - len_a) + first_num + "     "
            middle = middle + symbol + " " + " " * (len_c - len_b) + last_num + "     "
            bottom = bottom + "  " + total + "     "
    
    #assemble it
    joint = top, middle, lines, bottom
    answer = '\n'.join(joint)
    return answer
        
        

print(arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 8", "1 - 3801", "9999 + 9999", "523 - 49"]))
```

This is the output that i got

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvvgF.png)

The output that i expect to come is like this

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAkk2.png)

It only doubles the first and the last problem from the array and i don't know which part that's wrong

ps. sorry for the shitty ass lines of code I'm pretty new at this thing TT

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your outputs/errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if maxi == len_a:
    top = top + " "*2 + first_num + "     "
    middle = middle + symbol + " " + " " * (len_a - len_b) + last_num + "     "
    bottom = bottom + "  " + " " * (len_a - len_c) + total + "     "
if maxi == len_b:
    top = top + " "*2 + " " * (len_b - len_a) + first_num + "     "
    middle = middle + symbol + " " + last_num + "     "
    bottom = bottom + "  " + " " * (len_b - len_c) + total + "     "
else:
    top = top + " "*2 + " " * (len_c - len_a) + first_num + "     "
    middle = middle + symbol + " " + " " * (len_c - len_b) + last_num + "     "
    bottom = bottom + "  " + total + "     "
```

If `maxi == len_a`, the first `if` body will be executed, appending the result.  Then the second `if` condition will be evaluated, and if true, the `if` body will be executed, otherwise the `else` body will be executed.  Either way, the result is appended a second time.  Only one of those three cases should be executed on a given loop iteration.  You can fix it by changing the second `if` to an `elif`:

```
if maxi == len_a:
    top = top + " "*2 + first_num + "     "
    middle = middle + symbol + " " + " " * (len_a - len_b) + last_num + "     "
    bottom = bottom + "  " + " " * (len_a - len_c) + total + "     "
elif maxi == len_b:
    top = top + " "*2 + " " * (len_b - len_a) + first_num + "     "
    middle = middle + symbol + " " + last_num + "     "
    bottom = bottom + "  " + " " * (len_b - len_c) + total + "     "
else:
    top = top + " "*2 + " " * (len_c - len_a) + first_num + "     "
    middle = middle + symbol + " " + " " * (len_c - len_b) + last_num + "     "
    bottom = bottom + "  " + total + "     "
```

That way, only one case will be executed per loop iteration.